# What is the git command to check permissions on the current repo?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-push, git-clone

I am able to successfully clone a git repo.
I am trying to find out permissions on the current repo.

I have executed following command:

```
git shortlog -sne
```

Output:

```
2  LastName, FirstName <abc@domain.com>
```

I don't see any information related to access in the above output.
Please help me write the correct command to find permission/access on current repo

Comment: What do you mean by "permissions/access"?

Comment: Repositories do not have permissions. More specifically, *Git* does not do any permissions checking. It will store files in commits with an executable/not-executable bit, and when it uses files on a file system on an OS, it has some code in it to deal with Unix/Linux-style permission bits in the case of a shared-file-system (shared-drive) area, but this is quite limited.

Comment: Most *hosting providers* such as GitHub add their own layer of permissions/access-controls. Each provider uses a different scheme, though.